# Setting a Bitmap in Windows 7 thumbnail preview

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows-7, bitmap

I am currently using the [Windows 7 API Code pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) for an application I am coding in C#. 
Currently, I understand how to draw part of the Window region or a control into the thumbnail preview:

```
TaskbarManager.Instance.TabbedThumbnail.SetThumbnailClip((new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle, new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)v.X, (int)v.Y, (int)pictureBox1.RenderSize.Width, (int)pictureBox1.RenderSize.Height));
```

However, I am wanting to draw a Bitmap image into the thumbnail. There is an method for it, but it is not documented very well. The method to set a bitmap i:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmptest = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
tb.SetImage(bmptest)
```

That does work, but it still doesn't set the thumbnail preview of the (bmptest) bitmap.

I am wondering if there is anybody here who has an insight into the Windows 7 API code pack and if they could please point me into the right direction with how to set a bitmap image in the thumbnail preview.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with the Windows 7 API code pack, but the Bitmap class has a `GetThumbnailImage(...)` method which may give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom TabbedThumbnail first and the setting the image on the thumbnail...

[Here](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2009/10/14/anatomy-of-the-windows-7-taskbar-tabbedthumbnail-part-1.aspx) is a example of how to create your own TabbedThumbnail

```
preview = new TabbedThumbnail(this, this, VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(this));
```

Taken from this article!